# How can I order the filter menu in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, searchkit

Hi i am using reactjs searchkit component in my project. As a requirement, I need to list the filter menu order by alphabetical order

In the below picture, I need to order Actors list in alphabetical order, how can i do this?

[image]

Can anybody know how to do this?

Comment: The Searchkit docs have [an entire section entitled "Sorting"](https://ssetem.gitbooks.io/searchkit/docs/components/sorting/sort.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following code based on the assumption that that your RefinementFilterComponent is a stateless functional component.

Here is a link to dev docs related to lists and mapping.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

```
const sortActors = props.title.sort((a, b) => {
  const [aFirst, aLast] = a.split(' ');
  const [bFirst, bLast] = b.split(' ');
    return aLast > bLast ? 1 : -1;
})

const renderActors = sortActors
  .map(actor => 
    <li key={actor.toString()}>
      {actor}
    </li>
  )
```